# Wait for events based on time, child process ending, data arriving on file descriptor

Tags: c, linux

An app needs to be able to set callbacks on various events. The events can be any of:

- A UTC time has been reached
- Data has arrived at a file descriptor
- A child process has completed.

I need to write a function that will dispatch the events. The app will run on an embedded platform and should take reasonable steps to minimise CPU utilisation.

One approach would be a busy loop:

```
#define MAX_EVENT 10

typedef enum tagEventType {EV_DATA, EV_CHILD, EV_TIME} tEventType;
typedef void(*tEventCallback)(int);
typedef struct tagEvent
{
    int sequence;
    tEventType type;
    tEventCallback callback;
    time_t time;
    int fd;
    pid_t pid;    
} tEvent;

static tEvent eventsTable[MAX_EVENT];    

static void processEvents(void)
{
    int i;
    for ( i=0; i<MAX_EVENT; ++i )
    {
        if ( eventsTable[i].sequence > 0 )
        {
            switch(eventsTable[i].type)
            {
                case EV_DATA:
                    if ( checkForDataUsingPoll( eventsTable[i].fd) )
                    {
                        eventsTable[i].callback(eventsTable[i].sequence);
                    }                    
                    break;
                case EV_CHILD:
                    if ( kill(eventsTable[i].pid, 0) == -1 )
                    {
                        eventsTable[i].callback(eventsTable[i].sequence);
                        eventsTable[i].sequence = 0;                        
                    }
                    break;
                case EV_TIME:
                    {
                        if ( time(NULL) > eventsTable[i].time )
                        {
                            eventsTable[i].callback(eventsTable[i].sequence);
                            eventsTable[i].sequence = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(  int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    while(1)
    {
        processEvents();
        usleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

checkForDataUsingPoll() uses poll() with a timeout of zero to check whether data has arrived at the file descriptor. I've omitted it for brevity.

Is there a way of doing this which avoids the busy loop? Some mixture of poll, signals, and alarm perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file descriptors, there is `poll` (which you already use) or `select` or `epoll` or libevent. You can also check the `SIGIO` signal, or the functions prefixed with [`aio_`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/aio).

For the time, you can check the [`alarm`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm) system call.

For termination of child processes, check the `SIGCHLD` signal.

**Edit** To answer the comment: For the signals, you don't really have to do anything, the signal handlers you set will be called automatically by the system when they occur. If they happen set a flag and possible other variables to inform your program what happened.

When a signal is received, `poll` will return with an error and `errno` set to `EINTR`. If that is the case, check the flags set by the signal handlers to see what happened, and call whatever functions you need. If it was an alarm, then you have to restart the alarm for the next event. Then call `poll` again, waiting for the next event to occur.

Unless you have other things to do, you can even call `poll` with an infinite timeout. It will return on signals or file descriptor ready.

Comment: What I'm not clear on is how to simultaneously wait for poll,  SIGALRM  and SIGCHLD. I suppose the poll() will be interrupted by a signal. I'd then have to reissue alarm() for the next timed event...

Comment: @SimonElliott Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I don't need alarm() as I can just use poll() timeout.

Comment: @SimonElliott Of course! Seems I had a case of [the complicator](http://www.google.se/search?q=the+daily+wtf+complicator) for a moment. :)

Comment: Install a signal handler for SIGCHLD that sets a flag. poll() will return -1 and set errno == EINTR if a signal is caught while blocking on poll, check the flag on each round of doing poll (you'll actually need to play around with signal masks and use ppoll() in order to not have a race condition).

Comment: As an alternative, use the linux specific signalfd() and timerfd_create() ,which gives you file descriptors that you can use like any other file descriptor in poll() that delivers signal and timer events through a file descriptor.